# como manipular um objeto dentro de uma array no typeScript

Tags: array, angular, api, select, objetos

eu utilizo a ultima versão do angular, e estou tendo uma baita dificuldade para passar um valor para o campo, segue detalhes abaixo

estou puxando dados de uma api e enviando em lista para um select

```
<option *ngFor="let perfil of perfilAdd">{{perfil.name}}</option>
```

feito isso, ao selecionar eu preciso que ele me retorne **nome e id**, infelizmente o objeto **id** está null, então preciso que seja manipulado, para que ao selecionar ele retorne o valor certo..

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: o que está nulo é o item "perfil.id" ou a tag <option>? Se for a tag, você pode complementar com: <option [value]="perfil.id">{{perfil.name}}</option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você só quiser o valor do campo selecionado, nem precisa preencher o atributo `value`:

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let perfil of perfilAdd" >{{perfil.name}}</option>
</select>

onChange(deviceValue) {
    console.log(deviceValue);
}
```

Se você quiser manipular, binda o elemento `value` ao id do perfil.

```
<select [ngModel]="perfilSelecionado" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" name="sel2">
    <option [value]="perfil.id" *ngFor="let perfil of perfilAdd">{{perfil.name}}</option>
</select>

export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  perfilAdd = [{id:1, name:"nome1"},{id:2, name:"nome2"}];

onChange(event) {
  console.log (event);
}

}
```

[Mais detalhes nessa resposta.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700266/how-can-i-get-new-selection-in-select-in-angular-2)

[O código funcionando aqui.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bzc5op)